# Python - compare strings and count the appears time

Tags: python

I can not count how many time b appears in a

**input:** a = abcdebcf, b = bc

so **output should be** count = 2 because bc appears 2 time in a.

```
def maxcount(a, b):
        sum = 0
        for t in s:
            s = s.replace(t, '')
            sum += 1
        return sum
```

my code compare every single letters of b with every single letter in a. Then counts all of them. example output of my code is: count = 4. It should be 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use regex with the `re` module to match your pattern:

```
>>> import re
>>> a = 'abcdebcf'
>>> b = 'bc'
>>> re.findall('bc', a)
['bc', 'bc']

>>> len(re.findall('bc', a))
2
```

You can define your function like this

```
def maxcount(a, b):
    import re
    return len(re.findall(b, a))

print maxcount('abcdebcf', 'bc')

2
```

---

**Update**: from your comments, what you look for is a recursive function. This would look different, something like

```
import re

total = 0
a = 'xxyy'
b = 'xy'

while a:
    b_in_a = len(re.findall(b, a))
    if b_in_a < 1:
        break

    total += b_in_a
    a = a.replace(b, '')

print total
2
```

Comment: so, if we count bc then take it off the a string if after we took off, the new string creates a new bc.. so how can we count that one into maxcount?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, you want to create a new string without the `bc` occurences? You pass the function a string (`param a`) and a pattern you want to match (`param b`)

Comment: input: a = xxyy, b = xy. then we take xy out of xxyy count 1.. then it creates a new string xy.. then we have 1 more xy so we need to count that new xy into maxcount

Comment: This will return 1, as `xy` appears one in the string. Try the function

Comment: xxyy we count 1, then take that xy(midle xy) away then the first x and the last y create a new xy.. then we need to count so total should be 2

Comment: you're looking for a recursive function. I updated my answer with one

Comment: OH OK.. IT WORKED... sorry... :)))

Answer (score 0):

Another simple alternative to your particular example would be to make use of [count](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.count) function. In your case, there is no issue with overlapping.

```
a = "abcdebcf"
b = "bc"
count = a.count(b)
print(count)
```

Edit:

According to the request being made in comments, I am adding another way to solve the number of occurrences after replacement is made. Check this function. It replaces and keeps counting till the instance is found.

```
import re
a = "xxyy"
b = "xy"
count = 0
while True:
    a, c = re.subn(b, '', a)
    count += c
    if c == 0:
        break
print(count)
```

Comment: thank, but how about this:if a = xxyy, b = xy then we count 1, then we take that xy (midle xy) away then the first x and the last y create a new xy.. then we need to count that xy so total should be 2. how to do it?

Comment: Check the answer. I have edited my answer as per your requirements. Hope it helps you. :)

Comment: what I'm looking for is the program can work for any strings!

Answer (score 0):

You can try This:

```
sum = 0
c = ''
for letter in a:
    c = c + letter

    if b in c: 
        sum += 1
        c = ''
return sum
```